# Stopwatch localstorage for resume time React JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, time, local-storage, stopwatch

I'm building a web app that has a stopwatch feature, I developed it properly but did not store data(local storage). So, when the user re-loads and closes it, it will start from 0.

I want to keep this time data in "local storage" so that it will not start from 0 when the user closes or re-loads the website.

I keep these stopwatch functionalities in useStopwatch hook.

```
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";

export default function useStopwatch() {
  const [days, setDays] = useState(0);
  const [hrs, setHrs] = useState(0);
  const [mins, setMins] = useState(0);
  const [secs, setSecs] = useState(0);
  const [progressTime, setProgressTime] = useState(0);
  const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState<NodeJS.Timeout | undefined>();

  let startTime = 0;
  let elapsedTime = 0;

  const start = () => {
    startTime = Date.now() - elapsedTime;
    const id = setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
    setIntervalId(id);
  };

  const restart = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    setDays(0);
    setHrs(0);
    setMins(0);
    setSecs(0);
    startTime = 0;
    elapsedTime = 0;

    start();
  };

  const updateTime = () => {
    elapsedTime = Date.now() - startTime;
    const secs = Math.floor((elapsedTime / 1000) % 60);
    const mins = Math.floor((elapsedTime / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
    const hrs = Math.floor((elapsedTime / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 60);
    const days = Math.floor(elapsedTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    setDays(days);
    setHrs(hrs);
    setMins(mins);
    setSecs(secs);
    setProgressTime(elapsedTime);
  };

  return { days, hrs, mins, secs, progressTime, start, restart };
}
```

Same code in GitHub repo: https://github.com/rakibul-wdp/quit-zina/blob/main/hooks/useStopwatch.ts

Full project code: https://github.com/rakibul-wdp/quit-zina

How can I implement this "localstorage" feature for this stopwatch?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve using this one.

```js
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";

export default function useStopwatch() {
  const [days, setDays] = useState(0);
  const [hrs, setHrs] = useState(0);
  const [mins, setMins] = useState(0);
  const [secs, setSecs] = useState(0);
  const [progressTime, setProgressTime] = useState(0);
  const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState<NodeJS.Timeout | undefined>();

  const start = () => {
    const elapsedTime = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("elapsedTime"));
    localStorage.setItem("startTime", `${Date.now() - elapsedTime}`)
    const id = setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
    setIntervalId(id);
  };

  const restart = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    setDays(0);
    setHrs(0);
    setMins(0);
    setSecs(0);
    startTime = 0;
    elapsedTime = 0;

    start();
  };

  const updateTime = () => {
    const startTime = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("startTime"));
    const elapsedTime = Date.now() - startTime;
    localStorage.setItem("elapsedTime", `${elapsedTime}`);
    const secs = Math.floor((elapsedTime / 1000) % 60);
    const mins = Math.floor((elapsedTime / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
    const hrs = Math.floor((elapsedTime / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 60);
    const days = Math.floor(elapsedTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    setDays(days);
    setHrs(hrs);
    setMins(mins);
    setSecs(secs);
    setProgressTime(elapsedTime);
  };

  return { days, hrs, mins, secs, progressTime, start, restart };
}
```

Comment: It's work...!!!
But there is one issue. When I re-load it, it's not resume time, it just stuck.

I want to keep time progress and auto-resume when I reload.

Is it possible!

Comment: You need to call start method inside useEffect when you call useStopWatch() custom hook. It will continue from ending time until restart is called.

Comment: const { days, hrs, mins, secs, progressTime, start, restart } = useStopWatch();

useEffect(() => {
  start();
}, []);